# NSFetchresultsController crashes on deletion of dependent objects

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using the NSFetchResultsControlleDelegate Methods from this awesome Post:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/11/i-know-youre-tired-of-hearing-about.html
However:

I have the special situation that the objects in my tableview are connected to each other.
So: if I delete an object, I get 2 events in the callback: on for the `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` and one `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate`.

The method crashes in the NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete branch due  to a invalid indexPath.
I looked at it for a while and though of some workarounds for this but did not yet come up with a clean solution to that case.
Any hints ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the deleted object is the only object in it's table view section, the section of other objects will change. A section change will cause the indexPath to be changed as well. If you still try to access the object using the old indexPath, the app will crash.
To work around that, use the newIndexPath method parameter if it's available:

```
        NSIndexPath* ip = nil;
        if (newIndexPath != nil) {
            ip = newIndexPath;
        } else {
            ip = indexPath;
        }
        NSManagedObject *changedObject = [controller objectAtIndexPath:ip];
```

Hope that helps.
Cheers,
Christian